# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MKL_CBWR_Set

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, shared-libraries, intel-mkl, lnk2001

In a C++ project...

Project is linked to a lib which is integrating MKL. In the source code, I have this line

```
gaussNewton<5, 16>::myfunREE_33_GN_rsp_new(&inv_Controls, 
        &interOut, table_ENP3_local, coefForJacobian, interOut.vo);
```

when commented it is compiling, when uncommented there is this error...

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MKL_CBWR_Set
```

I suspect

- a link problem with MKL
- a problem related to visibility of template specialization

Have you seen such error before? What is this MKL_CBWR_Set ?

EDIT

Is there any issue related to call of static method with this syntax in case of template specialization:

```
gaussNewton<5, 16>::myfunREE_33_GN_rsp_new(&inv_Controls, 
        &interOut, table_ENP3_local, coefForJacobian, interOut.vo);
```

Comment: Seems to be a function from Intel's math lib: http://www.hpc.ut.ee/dokumendid/ics_2013/composer_xe/Documentation/en_US/mkl/mkl_userguide/GUID-507796B7-306A-4A67-8BF6-87174B89CBC0.htm .